# Adding a Tabcontrol to existing Tabcontrol C#

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I'm trying to dynamically add a new `Tabcontrol` into an existing `Tabcontrol`. I have Categories and Modules. Every Module is assigned to a Categorie. The Categories are shown in a `Tabcontrol`. Now I have to add another `Tabcontrol` with the Modules(which are Usercontrols) into the existing `Tabcontrol` with the Categories.

Thanks for the Help
Daniel

Comment: What stops you from adding it? What is the problem?

Comment: You can only add tabpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically this is how you would add a TabControl within a TabControl.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parentTabControl = new TabControl {Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
    parentTabControl.TabPages.Add("Parent Tab");
    var page = parentTabControl.TabPages[0]; // Get the index that is appropriate for your logic
    var childTabControl = new TabControl {Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
    childTabControl.TabPages.Add("Child Tab");
    page.Controls.Add(childTabControl);
    this.Controls.Add(parentTabControl);
}
```

If this doesn't answer you question then please let us know what error you are getting and post the portion of the code which is failing for you :).